# How to invoke a Python script automatically when VLC media process starts everytime on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, shell, ubuntu, vlc

I'm making a Python script that will save the song path whenever VLC media player runs on a Ubuntu System. The script is ready but if I run this script at the startup, it continuously uses cpu share in the loop. I want to invoke the script automatically whenever the user starts vlc media player. How can I do it? Can it be possible with any shell scripting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os,time

processname = 'enter the VLC process name'
tmp = os.popen("ps -Af").read()
proccount = tmp.count(processname)

while proccount > 0:
    print(proccount, ' processes running of ', processname, 'type')
    runsongpathfunction()
    time.sleep(1)
```

So what this does is it finds the process from the process name then when VLC is closed the script closes and it stops doing whatever it was doing while VLC was running because the while loop is no longer True. I added a time.sleep(1) to save resources its not really needed but it saves CPU.

Comment: So this script will invoke automatically whenever I run VLC on my system or I have to add this as the startup application?

Comment: You have to add the startup application and fill in the VLC process name variable. I would recommend using a chron job.

Comment: I'm facing two problems with this. First, if I add it as the startup application and if vlc is not running, it will break the while loop and the script will stop. Secondly, even if vlc is not running, it is giving me 4 proccesses running of 'vlc' type. WHY?